# Some google links appearing out of nowhere

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm taking over a project in Wordpress that was done by some other developer and going through it I realised that he has adjusted some premade theme and edited many areas of it.

And it works fine, BUT there are some  tags appearing on the homepage and messing up the website structure in IE8.
These links look simple, like this:  in Chrome's Inspect Element or Firebug, but when i load the source, they look like this:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank" rel="dofollow">
```

I tried removing ALL the scripts that are loading, all at once or one by one, but it persisted.

This is the website, so if you have any idea why this is happening, it would be awesome.

http://basicallyfood.implementek.net/demo/

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried searching the entire site's code base?

Comment: They are in the source, so they are included on the server. We can't see your server side code or the raw content of the database.

Comment: It is probably in your database through some widget or plugin. Check configurations of your banner plugin/widget.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the google.com links are only place holders and the developer forgot about them... just look inside your source code of the template, if you can't find it, do a grep search:

```
grep -lir "google.com" *
```

if it wont find anything, search for the string in your database, especially in wp_options